# nginx php file being downloaded in second identical case

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /srv/www/example.com;
    access_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log;

    location / {
            index index.html index.php;
    }

    location /site1 {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            index index.php index.html;
            root /srv/www/example.com;
    }

    #Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ /site1/.+\.php$ {
            set $php_root /srv/www/example.com;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $php_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /site2 {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            index index.php index.html;
            root /srv/www/example.com;
    }

    #Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ /site2/.+\.php$ {
            set $php_root /srv/www/example.com;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $php_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

When a user visits domain http://example.com, the file http://example.com/index.html is rendered in his browser (file path: /srv/www/example.com/index.html).

When a user visits domain http://example.com/site1, the file http://example.com/site1/index.php is rendered in his browser (file path: /srv/www/example.com/site1/index.php).

BUT when a user visits domain http://example.com/site2, the file http://example.com/site2/index.php is DOWNLOADED (file path: /srv/www/example.com/site2/index.php).

The config for site1 and site2 is identical. Why one works and one does not?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are doing quite many things wrong :)

First problem is that you are using duplicate `root` directives inside `location` blocks. Then you are using `$php_root` variable, when there is no need for it.

One small problem is also that you are writing your logs into a publicly accessible directory (under document root).

This is a simplified configuration that should accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /srv/www/example.com;
    access_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log;

    index index.html index.php;

    location /site1/ {
        alias /srv/www/example.com/site1/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location /site2/ {
        alias /srv/www/example.com/site2/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    # Alternative solution to the above two location blocks
    # location ~ /site(?<sitenr>[1-2])/ {
    #     alias /srv/www/example.com/site$sitenr/;
    # }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Here, we simply declare the `/site1` / `/site2` locations with `alias` directive, and then the `try_files` will try to serve the files. If the file is not found, the request is passed to the PHP processing block.

In PHP processing block, we use `$document_root` to pass the `alias` directory specification located in the `location` block.

Therefore we only need one PHP block, and the problem you had should be avoided.

In the alternative single `location` block example, I use regular expression to capture the referenced site number into a variable, and then use that variable for the `alias` directive. This further removes unnecessary duplication.

Comment: Hi there, I replaced my entire config with yours. It still doesn't work. When i go to the first site, i get a blank white page... and when i go to the second site, it still downloads the file.

Comment: What does the nginx logs tell on both occasions?